# Forcing mathematica to evaluate two different functions at same number of points, within equal range of the only and common independent variable

Tags: plotting, export

I have two functions `T1(x)` and `T2(x)`. My objective is to output the result of both as .csv files and then take the average.

The `x` range for both the functions is same but mathematica evaluates each of these functions at different number of points. How can I force mathematica to allow evaluation at same number of points for both the functions ?

The code for the first function is:

```
ww = 0.75 10^-3; wc = 
 0.25 10^-3; d = 0.002; L = 0.0252; u = 0.0133; cp = 4178; ks = 390; \
tfi = 300; rho = 996.497; h = 4683; 
m = Sqrt[(2*h)/(ks*ww)]; α = (2*h)/(cp*rho*u*wc); β = (2*h)/(ks*ww); p = Sqrt[α^2 + 4*β]; eta =Tanh[d*m]/(d*m); σ = d/wc;
γ = 26455.03/ks; 

Tw0[x_, y_] = (((α*γ)/E^(0.5*x*(α + p)))*((α - p)*E^(0.5*L*(α + p)) + E^(L*p)*(p - α) + 2*(α + β*x)*E^(L*p + 0.5*x*(α + p)) + (α + p)*E^(p*x)*(1 - E^(0.5*L*(α + p))) - 2*E^(0.5*x*(α + p))*(α + β*x)))/(2*β^2*d*(E^(L*p) - 1)) + (γ*Cosh[m*(d - y)])/(m*Sinh[d*m])  ; 

eqn = Derivative[3][y][x] == -((2*α*β*γ*d)/((d*m)^2 + (Pi*n)^2)) + (β + ((Pi*n)/d)^2)*Derivative[1][y][x] + α*((Pi*n)/d)^2*y[x] - α*Derivative[2][y][x]; 
eq = DSolve[{eqn, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][L] == 0, Derivative[2][y][0] - y[0]*(β + ((Pi*n)/d)^2) == 0}, y[x], x]; 
sol = eq[[1]];
sol = y[x] /. sol;
sol = sol*Cos[(Pi*n*y)/d]; 
Twn = Sum[sol, {n, 1, 10}];

Tsw[x_, y_] = Tw0[x, y] + Twn;

T1[x_] = Integrate[Tsw[x, y]/d, {y, 0, d}];

T1 = Cases[Plot[{T1[x]}, {x, 0, L}], Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]];

Export["T1.csv", T1]
```

The second function `T2(x)` is defined using the following code (Please note that I used two different kernels to evaluate each function, in order to avoid variable name overlap)

```
T2[x_]=(1/(2 (-1 + E^(L Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β])) β^2 Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]))E^(-L α - 1/2 x (3 α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β])) P (-2 E^(L α + 1/2 x (3 α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]))Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β] (α^2 + β + x α β) + 2 E^(L (α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]) + 1/2 x (3 α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]))Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β] (α^2 + β + x α β) + E^(x α + L (α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β])) α (α^2 + 4 β - α Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]) - E^(x α + 1/2 L (3 α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β])) α (α^2 + 4 β - α Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]) + E^(L α + x (α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β])) α (α^2 + 4 β + α Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]) - E^(x (α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]) + 1/2 L (3 α + Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β])) α (α^2 + 4 β + α Sqrt[α^2 + 4 β]))

β = 4002.564 
α = 42.265
P = 67833.40
L = 0.0252

T2 = Cases[Plot[{T2[x]}, {x, 0, L}], Line[data_] :> data, -4, 1][[1]];

Export["T2.csv", T2]
```

Comment: I am guessing if you replace `T1=Cases[Plot[{T1[x]},{x,0,L}]...` and `T2=Cases[Plot[{T2[x]},{x,0,L}]...` with
`t1=Table[{x,T1[x]},{x,0,L,L/100}];T1=Cases[ListPlot[t1,Joined->True]...` and 
`t2=Table[{x,T2[x]},{x,0,L,L/100}];T2=Cases[ListPlot[t2,Joined->True]...` that it will evaluate T1 and T2 at exactly the same horizontal coordinates and draw lines between those points as needed to be extracted by your code. You can change the L/100 to a different step size as needed. Please test this carefully and verify that it works exactly correctly.

Comment: @Bill Works perfectly ! If you write this as an answer, I will be happy to accept it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plot is "smart" and "adaptive" and the points at which it chooses to evaluate the function depend on the function. You can force your own evaluation points by using `Table` and `ListPlot`.

Replace

```
T1=Cases[Plot[{T1[x]},{x,0,L}]...
T2=Cases[Plot[{T2[x]},{x,0,L}]...
```

with

```
t1=Table[{x,T1[x]},{x,0,L,L/100}];
T1=Cases[ListPlot[t1,Joined->True]...
t2=Table[{x,T2[x]},{x,0,L,L/100}];
T2=Cases[ListPlot[t2,Joined->True]...
```

and that will force it to evaluate T1 and T2 at exactly the same horizontal coordinates and draw lines between those points as needed to be extracted by your code. You can change the L/100 to a different step size as needed.

You might also consider using different names for

```
T1[x_]=Integrate[...
```

and

```
T1=Cases[ListPlot[...
```

also

```
T2[x_]=Integrate[...
```

and

```
T2=Cases[ListPlot[...
```

Using the same name for a function and then for data worries me.

Please test this carefully and verify that it works exactly correctly.

Comment: Isn't the answer simply `Export["t2.csv", t1]` and `Export["T2.csv", t2]`, skipping the plots altogether?